# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir los datos de una tabla con javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Obtengo los datos por medio de una función en php

Este es mi form y lo muestro desde php:

```
public function show_search_form()
{
    $output .= '
    <form class="form" action="crearcotizacion.php?action=por_descripcion" onsubmit="return llenartabla_por_desc();" method="post">
     <div class="form-body">

     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="descripcion">Inserte Descripción O Palabra Clave:</label>
       <input type="text" id="descripcion" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Descripción" name="descripcion" autocomplete="off">
     </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <i class="icon-search"></i> Buscar
     </button>

   </div>
  </form>
   ';
    return $output;
}
```

Después hago la consulta:

```
public function select_by_descripcion()
{
    $query = "SELECT * from listado_general_01 
    where Descripcion LIKE '%". $this->postData['descripcion']."%';";

    //$params_query = array();

    if($rs = $this->sql->select($query, array()))
    {
        return $rs;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

En seguida devuelvo la tabla, aún sin el resultado obtenido de mi consulta...

```
public function show_table_results_descripcion()
    {
        $output .= '
        <div class="table-responsive" style="max-height:400px;" id="areaImprimir">
            <div class="card-block">
            <p>Resultados Totales: <strong>';
            foreach ($this->count_by_descripcion() as  $value)
            {
                $output .= $value['total_result'];
            }
            $output .= '
            </strong>
            </p>
            </div>


            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover mb-0 thead-inverse" id="tabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th># Parte</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        ';
        $output .= '
        <script>
        var datos = [';
        foreach ($this->select_by_descripcion() as  $value)
        {
            $output .= '
             '.(json_encode($value)).'
            ';
        }
        $output .= '
        ];
        </script>';
        return $output;
    }
```

Y enseguida mi función de javascript, que es aquí donde radica el problema...

```
function llenartabla_por_desc(datos) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var descripcion = document.getElementById('descripcion').value;

    var data_send = 'descripcion='+descripcion;

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '?action=por_descripcion',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data_send,
        success:function(resp){
            var d = '<tr>'+
                '<th># Parte</th>'+
                '<th>Descripción</th>'+
                '<th>Precio</th>'+
            '</tr>';

            for (var i = 1; i < datos.length; i++)
            {
                d+= '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+datos[i].id+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+datos[i].Descripcion+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+datos[i].Precio+'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
            }
            $("#tabla").append(d);
        }
    })
    return false;
}
```

El Error que me arroja es: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
En esta linea...

**`for (var i = 1; i < datos.length; i++)`**

Lo que quiero lograr es pintar la tabla de resultados tal y como si fuera un datagridview en c#, usando javascript para no generar un link extra con la variable "action" de php

Comment: Y qué contiene tu variable datos? Dónde la declaras?

Comment: Tu ajax retorna los resultados en el parámetro del `success` que has llamado `resp`. Por lo que sería `resp.length` y `resp[i].id` etc... A no ser que como comenta VickMuñoz la variable `datos` este declarada e iniciada antes del `ajax` en un sitio que no vemos.

Comment: La variable _datos_ la declaro en mi output de php, solo que no lo esta recibiendo a mi ajax @VickMuñoz

Comment: @x3k_js cambie el parametro de mi success, pero ahora me imprime todos los datos de la tabla de mi base de datos y no de mi consulta. Y ademas lo imprime como **undefinded**